# Loading time of each page with selenium python

Tags: python, html, eclipse, selenium

Helllo everyone,

Can you please anyone help to calculate the load time of each page. I want to do with performance analysis of web page. This below code works with the Complete execution time. But i want to calculate the each loading page after everyclick.

```
navigationStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
responseStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.responseStart")
domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")

backendPerformance_calc = responseStart - navigationStart
frontendPerformance_calc = domComplete - responseStart

print("Back End: %s" % backendPerformance_calc)
print("Front End: %s" % frontendPerformance_calc)
```

Can you anyone help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this js to perform this check:

```
state = driver.execute_script(" return document.readyState; ")
```

Or, you can simple add an explicit wait after a specific element and see when it was displayed, then do some math (when you clicked and when the element was displayed)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i want to get do automate the result and generate a report of each execution time.. Can you please help me with this